# How can I miminize read/wriites for my firestore project with groups that contains multiple documents and multiple users?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on a personal project that uses Firestore to store recipes and the ability to create groups that contain several recipes and several users, and I want to structure my database to minimize excessive read/writes.

Here is my current setup. I've omitted parts of the documents that are irrelevant:

```js
// recipe-id-1
recipe: {
  userID: 'user-id-1', // who the recipe owner is
  groups: ['group-id-1', 'group-id-2'], // groups this recipe is a part of
  users: { // all the users that have access to this recipe
    'user-id-1': {
      name: 'Alice',
      associatedGroups: ['group-id-1', 'group-id-2'] // what groups this user has access to the recipe through
    },
    'user-id-2': {
      name: 'Bob',
      associatedGroups: ['group-id-1']
    },
  }
}

// group-id-1
group: {
  users: {
    'user-id-1': {
      ...
    },
    'user-id-2': {
      ...
    },
  }
}
```

As you can see, all of my recipe querying is done directly on the recipe documents themselves. Here is my current problem: say I have 1000 recipes in a given group. If I add or remove a user from the group, then I have to update all 1000 recipes to modify the user's access to the recipe.

Aside from that issue, this setup makes querying very convenient for two scenarios while also abiding by security rules that ensure I have permission to access the recipe:

- `` db.collection('recipes').where(`users.${myUserID}.name`, '>', '') ``

  - This allows me to perform a retrieval of all of the recipes I have access to, be it my own recipes or other users' recipes through groups I am apart of
- `` db.collection('recipes').where(`users.${myUserID}.associatedGroups`, 'array-contains', 'group-id-1') ``

  - This allows me to retrieve all of the recipes within a certain group

Here are the things my project requires:

- A way to perform a universal search across all possible recipes you have permission to access
- A way to create a group that has multiple users and multiple recipes, and set  recipe access permissions accordingly

How can I achieve those goals without having to read/write 1000 times (in the example above) for each user?

Comment: I revised your question to remove the opinion-based request (among other things); asking for opinions or "the best way" is not allowed on SO, but you have what appears to be an objective requirement buried in the request... focus on that requirement instead of what's "best".

Comment: And, to address the question being asked, I don't use Firebase or Google Cloud stuff, but wouldn't groups or roles be the obvious choice here? Check a user's group membership or assigned roles, and grant permissions to those groups/roles. Role-based access is the standard for permissions in the tech industry.

Comment: @TylerH Just a FYI; Your point is on-point but Firebase doesn't have groups or roles of any kind. There are only users so user organization, permissions, roles or groups in Firebase has to be created by the developer.  OP: The problem you have is this; how your data is organized is dependent on the types of queries you want to run and in many cases, a 'convenient' structure may often be a more costly structure. If there are 1000 recipes and you want to add a user to all of those, well... that's 1000 writes (based on that structure). You could store a users recipes with a user instead.